# Let's Encrypt Win Simple Not Renewing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, lets-encrypt

I am using [Lets encrypt win simple](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple) but everytime I try to renew my cert it tells me that is been renewed but when I go to my site it tells me the cert is expired.

Anyone have any ideas how I can renew my cert?

Comment: Was the httpd restarted/reloaded after renewing the certs?

Comment: I am not sure what that means. I also tried another tool called certify and it also said it renewed my cert but browser still says it is expired.

Comment: The web server must load the new certificate first! Reload or restart the web server, whatever it is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Assuming this is IIS, no need to reload or restart the site or the server, but you still have to assign the new cert to the site binding in question. I don't know these products, so i don't now whether they are suppose to do this automatically.